# Is it an offence to make FOIA requestsrequests pseudonymously?

Tags: england-and-wales, freedom-of-information

Meet Bob, Bob has submitted a FOIA request to a public body under a pseudonym, which it has accepted and proceeded with fulfilling.

A few months after its fulfilment, it comes to light that Bob had actually been the one who submitted the FOIA request, not one with the name of his pseudonym.

Did Bob commit an offence by filing a FOIA request under the pseudonym?